# pyinstaller giving me the "No module named 'my module'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I wrote a code with PyQt5 and im trying to do an executable so i can open it on another pc.

Im using Python 3.9.7 and auto-py-to-exe

The head of my main.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

from functools import partial
import entries 
import database_operation
import extended_combobox
import login
import message_box

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
```

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
root
|-main.py
|-entries.py
|-database_operation.py
|-extended_combobox.py
|-login.py
|-message_box.py
```

The command line from auto-py-to-exe looks like this

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "path/to/my/file/main.py"
```

So when trying to execute the main.exe, I have this error

```
C:\Users\Admin>C:\Users\Admin\output\main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folder\main.py", line 8, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'entries'
[11892] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Are both the files in the same location? main.exe is just main.py in disguise, so it needs all the modules that you imported. os, sys and other built-in modules will be included in the exe, but custom modules will not be included. You have to manually move the extra dependencies and the exe to the same directory.

Comment: I figured it out, i had to add the directory to my pyinstaller command `-p DIR` , so that it will take the other modules ive done into consideration.